# Azure Authentication with two tenants

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, multi-tenant

we want to provide an Azure Web App. I just want to ask, if there is a solution for our authentication problem. We want to provide access for users from tweo different tenants. I only found the option for multi tenant authentication but we do not want to grant access for every tenant out there.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application in Azure AD can be either single-tenant or multi-tenant.
Here are some approaches you can take:

1. Make the app multi-tenant and check the issuer

   - Allows users from any tenant to sign in
   - Use the "/organizations" endpoint for authentication, or have 2 login buttons that use the tenant-specific endpoints
   - But your application can check the issuer in the ID token/access token and reject any issuer which is not one of those two
   - Downside of using /organizations is that this will not support external users who have been invited to either tenant, as they will sign in to their home tenant, which probably has a different issuer than what you accept
   - Using tenant-specific endpoints requires two login buttons, from which the user must select, which does allow external users to use the app too, but makes the UI a bit more complex
2. Make two single-tenant apps, one in each tenant

   - Will only allow sign in from either tenant
   - Requires usage of two login buttons, one for each tenant